# How to get all data certain website with Scrapy?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I'm currently learn scraping using scrapy, so I want to scrape data from this: https://www.espn.com/nba/stats/player or https://www.espn.com/nba/stats/player/_/season/2023/seasontype/2

if you go to the link you will see the `show more` button at the bottom data so im confuse about this because if i scrape that right now im only get 50 of data that, not what i want, so i decided to look up the `show more` button but its only a `href=#`

[image]

**[UPDATE] USING Scrapy+playwright**

```
def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url='https://www.espn.com/nba/stats/player/_/season/2023/seasontype/2',
            meta= dict(
                playwright = True,
                playwright_include_page=True,
                playwright_page_coroutines = [
                    PageMethod('wait_for_selector','//a[@class="AnchorLink loadMore__link"]'),
                    PageMethod('click','//a[@class="AnchorLink loadMore__link"]'),
                ]
            ),
            callback=self.parse,
        )

    async def parse(self, response):
        page = response.meta['playwright_page']

        button = response.meta['playwright_page_coroutines'][0]
        if button:
            await button.click()

            resp = response.body
            player_list = sel.xpath(
                "//table[@class='Table Table--align-right Table--fixed Table--fixed-left']//tbody//tr")
            stats_list = sel.xpath(
                "//div[@class='Table__ScrollerWrapper relative overflow-hidden']/div[@class='Table__Scroller']/table/tbody/tr")

            await page.wait_for_selector(player_list)
            
            sel = Selector(text=resp)

            for player, stat in zip(player_list, stats_list):
                    player_name = player.xpath(".//a/text()").get()
                    position = stat.xpath(".//td/div/text()").get()
                    team_name = player.xpath(".//span/text()").get()
                    game_played = stat.xpath(".//td[2]/text()").get()
                    minutes_per_minute = stat.xpath(".//td[3]/text()").get()
                    points_per_game = stat.xpath(".//td[4]/text()").get()
                    fields_goal_made = stat.xpath(".//td[5]/text()").get()
                    fields_goal_attempted = stat.xpath(".//td[6]/text()").get()
                    field_goal_percentage = stat.xpath(".//td[7]/text()").get()
                    three_point_goal_made = stat.xpath(".//td[8]/text()").get()

            yield {
                        "player_name": player_name,
                        "player_position": position,
                        "team_name": team_name,
                        "game_played": game_played,
                        "minutes_per_minute": minutes_per_minute,
                        "points_per_game": points_per_game,
                        "fields_goal_made": fields_goal_made,
                        "fields_goal_attempted": fields_goal_attempted,
                        "field_goal_percentage": field_goal_percentage,
                        "three_point_goal_made": three_point_goal_made,
                    }
```

**When only using scrapy**

```
 def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url='https://www.espn.com/nba/stats/player/_/season/2023/seasontype/2',
            callback=self.parse,
        )
 def parse(self, response):
        sel = Selector(text=response.body)

        player_list = sel.xpath("//table[@class='Table Table--align-right Table--fixed Table--fixed-left']//tbody//tr")
        stats_list = sel.xpath("//div[@class='Table__ScrollerWrapper relative overflow-hidden']/div[@class='Table__Scroller']/table/tbody/tr")

        for player,stat in zip(player_list,stats_list):
            player_name = player.xpath(".//a/text()").get()
            position = stat.xpath(".//td/div/text()").get()
            team_name = player.xpath(".//span/text()").get()
            game_played = stat.xpath(".//td[2]/text()").get()
            minutes_per_minute= stat.xpath(".//td[3]/text()").get()
            points_per_game = stat.xpath(".//td[4]/text()").get()
            fields_goal_made = stat.xpath(".//td[5]/text()").get()
            fields_goal_attempted = stat.xpath(".//td[6]/text()").get()
            field_goal_percentage = stat.xpath(".//td[7]/text()").get()
            three_point_goal_made = stat.xpath(".//td[8]/text()").get()

            yield {
                "player_name": player_name,
                "player_position":position,
                "team_name": team_name,
                "game_played": game_played,
                "minutes_per_minute": minutes_per_minute,
                "points_per_game": points_per_game,
                "fields_goal_made":fields_goal_made,
                "fields_goal_attempted":fields_goal_attempted,
                "field_goal_percentage":field_goal_percentage,
                "three_point_goal_made":three_point_goal_made,
            }
```

Am i doing it wrong here? also if you click show more it will show the api like down bellow, i can scrape from that api but for now i want it from html with xpath it self.

[image]

Comment: You need to click the show more button, that is what activates the javascript to show more results.  I don't know much about splash so I am not sure if scrapy splash offers the ability to do this.

Comment: @Alexander so how to achieve this, should i combine with selenium?

Comment: Selenium would work, as would playwright.  Splash might work as well, I just don't know if it does or not.  Playwright and selenium i know would both work.

Comment: @Alexander I'm using windows I think the playwright does not work on windows also the scrapy-selenium does not have the latest update.

Comment: You are right, I always use a ubuntu VM for playwirght

Comment: @Alexander so I change it from using splash to playwright , but still I confuse how to click the button when available

Comment: you should close this question and open a new one tagging scrapy-playwright with the details of your issue.